# Is it possible to Develop Apps for multiple Smart TV using any single platform

Tags: sdk, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

Is it possible to develop single App for Multiple Smart TV ? I am looking forward to develop an App for Multiple Smart TVs using any single IDE / Platform.

Comment: Hello, could you please update with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are library that allows to start one application on a few smartTV platforms. Called SmartBox.

Look at this:
https://github.com/immosmart/smartbox